# Android - how to read subarray values from JSON depends on the selected item

Tags: android, json, listview

I have a JOSN file with following structure

```
[
    {
        "category" : "Category - 1",
        "table":[
            {
                "id" : 1,
                "title" : "Sample Title 1"
            },
            {
                "id" : 2,
                "title" : "Sample Title 2"
            },
            {
                "id" : 3,
                "title" : "Sample Title 3"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "category": "Category - 2",
        "table":[
            {
                "id" : 1,
                "title" : "Sample Title 1"
            },
            {
                "id" : 2,
                "title" : "Sample Title 2"
            },
            {
                "id" : 3,
                "title" : "Sample Title 3"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

First I have load all "category" values to a listview such as "Category - 1","Category - 2".
When I select "Category - 1" item from listview, I want to load/read items only from "Category - 1" table and when I select "Category - 2" item from the listview, I want to load/read the items only from "Category - 2" table.

Please let me know how to read the table field values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just parse the JSON and add it to your ListView's adapter.

```
JSONArray categories = new JSONArray(jsonString);
for (int i = 0; i < categories.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject category = categories.getJSONObject(i);

    String categoryName = category.getString("category");
    JSONArray table = category.getJSONArray("table");
    for (int k = 0; k < table.length(); k++) {
        JSONObject object = table.getJSONObject(k);

        int id = object.getInt("id");
        String title = object.getString("title");
    }
}
```

Comment: Let me do it and let you know the result. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this way u can get all Category and he's sub items.

```
    JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(json);
    HashMap<String, List<SubItem>> map = new HashMap<String, List<SubItem>>();
    for(int i=0; i<arr.length(); i++){
        JSONObject obj = arr.getJSONObject(i);
        String category = obj.getString("category");

        JSONArray table = obj.getJSONArray("table");

        List<SubItems> subITems = new ArrayList<SubItems>();
        for(int j=0; j<table.length(); j++){
            JSONObject item = table.getJSONObject(j);

            SubItem sub = new SubItem();
            sub.setId(item.getInt("id"));
            sub.setTitle(item.getString("title"));

            subITems.add(sub);
        }
        map.put(category, subITems);
    }
```